# How do I run an ADFS Claims-Aware Agent on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, adfs

I'm trying to create a development environment for a .NET web site but I'm stuck at one point. The authentication for the web site is going to be through ADFS and the development machines we have are Windows 7 machines. The web site is therefore running on IIS under Windows 7 but I can find no information on how to install the claims-aware agent on a Win 7 machine (I've so far only been able to find information for Server 2008).

Any suggestions on how to get a ADFS claims-aware site up and running on a Win7 machine would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a claims-aware agent on client. It's all in the bindings...

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787612(v=ws.10).aspx. There sure is and it's not delivered with win7 as oppossed to WinServer2008

Answer (score 2):

ADFS 1.0 Client Library (System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn) got replaced with ADFS 2.0 (Geneva / Windows Identity Foundation / Microsoft.IdentityModel).

.Net 4.5 replaced the separate WIF assemblies by moving the Claims identity model into System.IdentityModel.

Long and short, it is time to update that authentication code - it has already been superseded twice, and is now baked into the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you inquiring about ADFS 1.0 or 2.0? If you install WIF you will be able to develop claims aware applications on W7 using Visual Studio while using ADFS 2.0 for the STS.  Get the WIF SDK at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4451 and see the samples.

I am not aware of a claims web agent for W7. The web agent that is visible 2008/R2 while using the server manager's add roles functionality is for ADFS 1.0.